# Editing Sublime3 blackboard theme highlighting

Tags: linux, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am aware this has been asked on here before- none of the answers helped me.

In the sublime_text_3 folder I can see Packages and inside that I can see Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package. However, for some unknown reason somebody decided this should be zipped. Not being an advanced Linux user I am a little puzzled how I am to edit this file, to change the Blackboard theme settings and modify "selection" (for the highlighting color).

When I double-click Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package I get Ark pop-up, showing me all the various sub-themes, including Blackboard. However, how do I edit the Blackboard part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be best to copy the Blackboard theme, and save it as your own - this means that if a Sublime Text update overwrites the default Blackboard theme, you won't lose your changes.

You can get hold of the Blackboard theme, and edit it, using online tools such as;

http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Blackboard

You then save your new editing Blackboard theme into the `Sublime Text 3/data/Packages/User/` directory.

However if you have SublimeLinter installed, I find on my Mac Sublime Text, that if I set my theme to one of the defaults (Sublime Text > Preferences > Color Scheme > Color Scheme - Default > Blackboard), it creates a copy of the theme you've chosen, and stores it as;

```
Sublime Text 3/data/Packages/User/Blackboard (SL).tmTheme
```

You could then edit that with the changes you need.

Comment: Thanks! Btw which attribute do I need to change so that if I am searching for a word, it will highlight all instances of that word? At the moment it is only putting a silver border around (and the change I made only works on find next)

Comment: @user997112 the attributes you want are 'caret' (outline), 'findHighlight' (selected text background) and 'findHighlightForeground' (selected text colour).  FYI changing caret colour also changes the blinking text cursor.

Comment: I have no findHighlight in my blackboard theme, do I need to add this to my preferences.sublime-settings? Or do I create a findHighlight in blackboard?

Comment: @user997112 it just needs adding under the 'settings' key like 'caret' - <key>findHighlight</key><string>#FFE792</string><key>findHighlightForeground</key><string>#000000</string>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to edit zipped `.sublime-package` resources in Sublime Text 3 is to use the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeResourceViewer) plugin from Package Control. Once installed, open the Command Palette and type in ***`prv`*** to access the ***P***ackage***R***esource***V***iewer options. Select `Open Resource`, scroll down to `Color Scheme - Default`, then down to `Blackboard.tmTheme`. You can now edit the color scheme to your liking, and when you save, it will be placed in `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Blackboard.tmTheme`, where `Packages` is the directory opened by selecting the **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** menu option. Now, if you want to make further changes in the future, you can just open this file directly, instead of using PackageResourceViewer again.